# Seek Bar Steps Values to a Billion

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I tried several solutions from the seek bar step values question from stack, unfortunately none of it work for my case. The maximum number for my problem is 1,000,000,000. Each steps is increased by 1000.The problem was it does not increase gradually by 1000.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SeekBar mSb;
private TextView mTv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_a);
    mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mSb.setMax(1000000);
    mSb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        double iPoint ;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

             iPoint=progress*1000;
            if(seekBar.getProgress()==0){
                mTv.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            }else{
                mTv.setText(String.valueOf(iPoint));
            }


        }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep it between (0-100) and multiply by factor in `onProgressChanged()`.

Comment: "The maximum number for my problem is 1,000,000,000. Each steps is increased by 1000." -- this implies 1,000,000 steps. Even the highest resolution displays are only a few thousand pixels wide, which means that each step would be a tiny fraction of a pixel. Now, your code shows a maximum number of 1,000,000, but even this implies a step size of probably 2 pixels at most, which is still very small.